# RecyclerView item focus on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm working on `Android TV` application where I have a `recycler view`. How can I set focus on wanted position? (I've already tried `scrollToPosition` and `smoothScroller`, but it doesn't work). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the `setFocusable(true)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` methods on the item view.

An example:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ProgrammeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item_programme, parent, false);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    sDefaultBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), android.R.color.transparent);
    sSelectedBackgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#66ffe680");

    updateEPGTitleRowBackgroundColor(view, false);

    view.setOnFocusChangeListener(mOnFocusChangeListener);
    view.setOnKeyListener(mOnKeyListener);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

**Edit:**

You can try calling the

```
mRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).requestFocus();
```

method to focus a specific item. Just replace the 0 with the item index you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm already getting the focus on TV and items are focusable. The thing is I want to set focus on certain position when fragment launches.

Comment: this answer worked for me thank u